# Redux form can't able to update new values once the form is initialized

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am using redux wizard form for edit in which i am loading the data in componentDidMount for each page in the wizard. But when i update the values and go to next page the updated value is not refelcted in the second form whereas if i come to the previous page it loads the inital values instead of the updated values.
can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code:

First Form:

```
componentDidMount() {
const users = this.props.users;
let user = {};
user = users[this.props.userID];
this.setState({file: user.profilePicture});
this.props.initialize(user);
console.log('user is', user);
}

render() {


const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
  const age = (value) => (value == null ? '' : this.state.age);
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Col sm="12">
        <Card className="card-border">
          <CardBody>
            <FormGroup row>
              <Col xs="12" lg="2">
                <img
                  src={this.state.file}
                  style={{width: 125, height: 125}}
                  className="img-avatar"
                />
              </Col>
              <Col xs="12" lg="10">
                <Field
                  type="file"
                  id="file-input"
                  name="image"
                  accept="image/*"
                  component={ImageUpload}
                  label="Upload User Image *"
                  validation="fieldRequired"
                  className="fileLoader"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup row>
              <Col xs="12" lg="6">
                <Field
                  name="name"
                  type="text"
                  component={FormInput}
                  label="Name *"
                  inputPlaceHolder="Enter Name"
                  normalize={captialize}
                />
              </Col>
              <Col xs="12" lg="6">
                <Field
                  name="mobileNo"
                  type="text"
                  component={FormInput}
                  label="Mobile No *"
                  inputPlaceHolder="+91"
                  normalize={mobile}
                />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
          </CardBody>
          <div style={{ paddingBottom: 30 }}>
            <Button color="primary" className="btn-pill pull-right" type="submit" style={{marginRight: '20px'}}>
               Next &nbsp;
              <i className="fa fa-chevron-right" />
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    </form>
  );
} 
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'userEditForm',
  keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true,
  enableReinitialize: true,
  validate
})(UserGeneralForm);
```

Second Form:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const users = this.props.users;
    let user = {};
    user = users[this.props.userID];
    this.props.initialize(user);
    console.log('users detail in Personaldetail form', user);
  }


 render() {
  const { handleSubmit, previousPage } = this.props;
  const users = this.props.users;
  let user = {};
  user = users[this.props.userID];
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Col sm="12">
        <Card className="card-border">
          <CardBody>
            <Field
              name="address"
              type="textarea"
              component={FormInput}
              label="Address *"
              inputPlaceHolder="Enter Address"
            />
            <FormGroup row>
              <Col xs="12" lg="6">
                <Field
                  name="pincode"
                  type="text"
                  component={FormInput}
                  label="Pin Code *"
                  inputPlaceHolder="Enter Pin Code"
                  normalize={pinCode}
                />
              </Col>
              <Col xs="12" lg="6">
                <Field
                  name="qualification"
                  type="text"
                  component={FormInput}
                  label="Qualifications *"
                  inputPlaceHolder="Enter Qualifications"
                />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup row>
              <Col xs="12" lg="6">
                <Field
                  name="userOccupation"
                  type="text"
                  component={FormInput}
                  label="Occupation *"
                  inputPlaceHolder="Enter Occupation"
                />
              </Col>

              <Col xs="12" lg="6">
                <Field
                  name="income"
                  type="text"
                  component={FormInput}
                  label="Annual Income *"
                  inputPlaceHolder="Enter Annual Income"
                  normalize={salary}
                />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup row>
              <Col xs="12" lg="6">
                <Field
                  name="pan"
                  type="text"
                  component={FormInput}
                  label="PAN No *"
                  inputPlaceHolder="Enter PAN number"
                  normalize={(upper, pan)}
                />
              </Col>

              <Col xs="12" lg="6">
                <Field
                  name="aadhaar"
                  type="text"
                  component={FormInput}
                  label="Aadhaar No *"
                  inputPlaceHolder="Enter Aadhaar number"
                  normalize={aadhaar}
                />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup row>
              <Col xs="12" lg="6">
                <FormGroup>
                  <Field
                    name="maritalStatus"
                    component={DropDowns}
                    label="Marital Status *"
                    selectPlaceHolder="Please Select Marital Status"
                    datas={constants.maritalStatus}
                    editedData={user.maritalStatus}
                  />
                </FormGroup>
              </Col>
              <Col xs="12" lg="6">
                <FormGroup>
                  <Field
                    name="gender"
                    component={DropDowns}
                    label="Gender *"
                    selectPlaceHolder="Please Select Gender"
                    datas={constants.gender}
                    editedData={user.gender}
                  />
                </FormGroup>
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
          </CardBody>
          <div style={{ paddingBottom: 30 }}>
            <Button
              color="primary"
              className="btn-pill pull-left"
              onClick={previousPage}
              style={{ marginLeft: '20px' }}
            >
              <i className="fa fa-chevron-left" />
              &nbsp; Previous
            </Button>
            <Button
              color="primary"
              className="btn-pill pull-right"
              type="submit"
              style={{ marginRight: '20px' }}
            >
              Next &nbsp;
              <i className="fa fa-chevron-right" />
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For form 1st you need to create to connect your form via mapStatetoprops and mapDispatchToProps and in mapstatetoprops set your initialvalues that will fill during compomentdidmount
And in mapdispatchtoprops dispatch the action that will update your form during update....
And at the end pass your mapdispatchtoprops and mapstatetoprops in connect method arguments and export your form in the connected compoment
Like below. [image]